# How to do this integral without the inverse hyperbolic tan

Tags: calculus, integration

We have the integral $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{x^2+4x+3} dx$. I figured out that with a substitution you can rewrite this as $ - \displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{1-u^2} du$, which is $-\tanh^{-1}(u)$. However, I wonder if there's another way to do this integral without having to use the (in my opinion) obscure inverse hyperbolic trig functions.

Comment: Inverse hyperbolic tanh = $$\frac12 \log{\left ( \frac{1-u}{1+u} \right )}$$

Comment: @RonGordon I wasn't familiar with that identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply parital fractions to this problem and then simply integrate fractions by logarithms.

$$\frac{1}{x^2+4x+3}=\frac{1}{2(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2(x+3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x^2+4x+3}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+3)}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+3})$$
and then use the
$$\int \frac{1}{x+a}dx=\log|(x+a)|+C$$